# Getting int value from combo box in Java

Tags: java, swing, combobox

I was struggling to get int values from a column in a database into a combo box, so that once selected the values would print out in a textbox when I deviced this solution:

```
private void jComboBoxSNActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            

    JComboBox jComboBoxSN = (JComboBox) evt.getSource();
    int s_n = (Integer) jComboBoxSN.getSelectedItem();
    System.out.println("Number: " + s_n);
}
```

I want to know, this acceptable programming or bad programming?

Comment: What exactly do you not like about your code? Except for the naming of the int variable et doesn't look too bad.

Comment: Was wondering if the "int s_n = (Integer)jComboBoxSN.getSelectedItem();" is good programming or bad programming, that's all :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you are certain that your combo box cannot contain null values (and this is uncertain if you are loading the values from a database), then the code you have shown is not safe. This line:

```
int s_n = (Integer) jComboBoxSN.getSelectedItem();
```

will result in a NullPointerException if executed on a null item. (Auto-unboxing a null primitive wrapper is a NullPointerException).

An alternative would be to check for null before converting Integer to int:

```
Integer i = (Integer)jComboBoxSN.getSelectedItem();
if (i != null) {
    int s_n = i;  // or s_n = i.intValue();
}
```

However, I think something like this would be more suitable:

```
    final JTextArea text = new JTextArea();
    JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
    combo.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                // assume single selection
                int i = (Integer)e.getItemSelectable().getSelectedObjects()[0];
                text.setText("Selected [" + i + "]");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Ok, i see. How do I fix this potential problem?

Comment: Check for null before [unboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html). I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

**If** what you stored in the combo box are `Integer`s, then this is acceptable. Otherwise it is not.

You'll get the object you added at the selected position with `getSelectedItem()`. If you want the *index* of that item in the combo box, use `getSelectedIndex()` (which returns an int).

(Note: without knowing what class of objects you put in there, it's a bit hard to guess what you actually want out of it.)

Comment: The combo box gets its values from a column in a MS Access database table called "ANCHOR". The column name is "s_n" and it's data type is "Number", which is a long integer. Does that mean the combo box is storing Integer? If not, how then do I write an acceptable set of codes to remove an int from the combo box?

Comment: The combo box stores _what you put in it_. Only you can know what it is. Use a debugger or `println`s to figure out what type is stored. To remove an item, use `removeItem(Object)` or `removeItemAt(int)` depending on whether you have the stored item you want to remove or its index.

Comment: "The combo box stores what you put in it. Only you can know what it is." And as I said, the combo box gets its value from a column that stores only numbers, nothing more. Not text, not pictures, just numbers. The column can't store anything other than numbers, which essentially means the combobox can't take in anything other than numbers - ive preset it that way. What I'm asking is, based on the fact that the column stores numbers described as "long integers" does that make "int s_n = (Integer)jComboBoxSN.getSelectedItem();" correct programming or not?

Comment: "numbers" is not a Java type. _Your code_ adds stuff to the combo box, so _your code_ knows the type (even if you don't). Look at the API you're using to get the values from the database, and look at the method type signatures to figure out what types you are storing in the combo box.